# Maytag top loading washing machine full of water at end of cycle

Tags: washing-machine

The machine begins to agitate but I never stick around the whole time.  All I know is that at the end of the cycle it's sometimes filled with water.  But most of the time it's not.  This happened a few times in a row a month ago and then didn't happen again until today.  When this happens I typically turn the wash dial back to the middle of a wash cycle and it begins to spin.  Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the washer particularly full when this happens, or are you setting it correctly for the load size?  If the clothes can't move freely in the water, they can clump together on one side of the drum, causing it to be unbalanced when it starts to spin.  Your washing machine is then stopping at that point in its cycle to prevent it from damaging itself, or from walking across your laundry room floor.

Comment: i usually do full loads.  i'll definitely try to experiment with slightly smaller loads using the same load setting.  thanks!